# Sort numbers in ascendant order except specific number

Tags: javascript

How can I sort an array of numbers in ascendant order except 0 (which need to go at last). Example

```
[1,4,6,3,0,3,0,1] => [1,1,3,3,4,6,0,0]
```

I've tried `arr.sort((a,b)=>a>b && a!=0)` but doesn't work

Comment: `a > b && a != 0` is either true or false, which implies either `a` > `b` or `a` = `b`, respectively, and never `a` < `b`. Please read the [`sort` docs, especially how the return value works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try sorting by the difference between `a === 0` and `b === 0` (coerce the booleans to numbers), or if there is no difference, then sort by `a - b`:

```js
const arr = [1,4,6,3,0,3,0,1]
arr.sort((a,b) => ((a === 0) - (b === 0)) || a - b)
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 5):

The comparison function is supposed to return a number, not `true/false`.

Check for either number being `0` first. If it is, return either `1` or `-1` depending on whether it's the first or second argument.

Otherwise, return a normal comparison value.

```js
const arr = [1, 4, 6, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b == 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});

console.log(arr);
```